# HijriCalendar does not exist

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, globalization, cultureinfo, hijri

I am trying to get the current Hijri date in my Xamarin app.

I tried:

```
Calendar hijri = new HijriCalendar();
```

and

```
Calendar hijri = new HijriCalendar();
```

but getting:

> Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HijriCalendar' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246)

although I already added the:

```
using System.Globalization
```

Comment: Add the package `System.Globalization.Calendars`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HijriCalendar` is available in [.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?view=netstandard-2.0&term=HijriCalendar) and not in old good PCL.
So update your project to latest and greatest .NET Standard 2.0:

1. Unload your PCL project (right click -> unload), and start editing
   it (right -> click edit)
2. Delete Everything in the csproj and insert this:

```html
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <!--<PackageReference Include="" Version=""/>-->
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

3. Add back NuGets (simply open packages.config, and add the package references above, or via the NuGet package manager.
4. Delete AssemblyInfo.cs (this is now in the csproj) and packages.config (also in csproj via PackageReference)

[Original gist](https://gist.github.com/yuv4ik/063a35fe3986e62d69aee2f0ed0607bf).
If you are working with Visual Studio for Mac you can use [an extension](https://github.com/yuv4ik/Mutatio) to convert the project type automatically.

P.S.: Alternatively as suggested by SushiHangover you can add a NuGet package. However, I would recommend to switch to .NET Standard asap.
P.S.S: More about .NET Standard [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/net-standard?tabs=vsmac).

Comment: I am using Visual Studio for Mac but I didn't understand point 3 and 4 please.. which package I should add?

Comment: If you are on Mac use Mutatio => https://github.com/yuv4ik/Mutatio it is extension that will automatically convert the project for you. Check the Installation section in the link I shared.

Comment: If you still want to convert the project manually check the next video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F0VWCmj2adw

Comment: Don't see a point in doing it manually since there is a way to automate the process. BTW I am the author of this extension.

Comment: I started doing it manualy :) I have a question here please.. Do I also need to add packages such as Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms, Microsoft.NETCore.Targets, NETStandard.Library, System.IO, System.Runtime, etc

Comment: You should have a packages.json or project.json where all the NuGet packages should be listed. Most probably you will not need all of them in the new type of project. So start with all the external packages non ms ecosystem related and see ...

Comment: Then please accept and upvote the answer as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I have one last question please.. I have done this for the PCL project but do I need to do it for the other two projects in my solution, iOS and Droid?

Comment: No, you cant. For more details check the links to official documentation in my answer.